# No. of ways to arrange k types of things in n places

Tags: math, permutation, combinations

ok the problem is this:
I have 2 places and two types of cards A and B. In how many ways can I arrange these at the given two places. For this scenario, answer is :

```
AA
AB
BA
BB
```

so  4.

similarly for other cases like 3 places and 2 types of cards or 4 places and 5 types of cards.

**What is the general formula for this ?**

Comment: you should post math oriented questions in [math stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/), usually you will get better answers there.

Comment: why is this question tagged "algorithm"? there's no algorithm. it's just a simple formula.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `p` places and `k` types of cards, the formula is `pow(k, p)`, that is `k` to the power `p`.

Comment: Or to put it another way, all the p-digit numbers in base k.